# ElasticSearch NEST - Find results with special characters

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to write a search query on an elastic index that will return me results from any part of the field value.

I have a `Path` field that contains values like `C:\temp\ab-cd\abc.doc`

I want the ability to send a query that will return my any matching part from what I wrote

```
QueryContainer currentQuery = new QueryStringQuery
{
      DefaultField = "Path",
      Query = string.Format("*{0}*", "abc"),

};
```

The above will return results, this will not:

```
QueryContainer currentQuery = new QueryStringQuery
{
      DefaultField = "Path",
      Query = string.Format("*{0}*", "ab-cd"),

};
```

The same goes for any other special character like **@#$%^&*** and so on.

Is there some generic way to send a query and to find exactly what I searched?

Each of my fields are `multi-fields` and I can use the `*.raw` options but do not exactly know how or if I should

Comment: How do you search? SQL Server? Linq Query? Regular Expression? ...

Comment: I am searching on  mongo DB with River plugin using ElasticSearch

Comment: @gilkr what analyzer(s) have you used on the `Path` field?

Comment: @Russ Cam The default analyzer and the raw field is not analyzed

Comment: Use keyword analyzer on that filed. But be aware that *{ str }* is not so good in terms of performance

Comment: I need my performance to be fast. we have 20+ million records to search on and we need instant response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use nGrams to split the text in smaller chunks and use `term` filter to query it. Pro: it should be faster. Con: the size of the index (disk space) will be larger because more terms (from nGram filter) are generated.

```
PUT /test
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_ngram_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": [
            "substring"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "substring": {
          "type": "nGram",
          "min_gram": 1,
          "max_gram": 50
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        "Path": {
          "type": "string",
          "index_analyzer": "my_ngram_analyzer",
          "search_analyzer": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the query:

```
GET /test/test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "Path": {
        "value": "\temp"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you wish, you can use the config above as a sub-field for whatever mapping you already have.

If you want to use `query_string` there one thing you need to be aware: you need to escape special characters. For example `-`, `\` and `:` (complete list [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_reserved_characters)). Also, when indexing, the `\` char needs escaping, otherwise it will issue an error. This is what I tested especially with `query_string`: https://gist.github.com/astefan/a52fa4989bf5298102d1

Comment: I did Exactly what you wrote, and it created everything OK, but  the query does not return any result.

Should i have done anything else?

Comment: Hm, maybe I didn't test this properly. Can you give me some sample documents that should have returned and they  didn't?

Comment: You can test it with the example i gave in the original question: Path : "C:\temp\ab-cd\abc.doc"

Comment: @gilkr I updated my answer with a gist. Tested this with 1.6.0 and 1.7.1, with `query_string`.

Comment: @gilkr  Can you share your CSharp code here for saving the data and to search the same ?